# Failing to load resources in an executable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, resources, executable-jar

My code executes as expected in Eclipse, but when I attempted to export it to an executable jar, it stopped loading resources.  I looked at a lot of examples here, but couldn't seem to figure out what I had done wrong.  I reviewed the jar contents and the resource files are all there.  The hierarchy in the jar is:

```
/src/code
/resources files
```

Within Eclipse project the hierarchy is

```
/src/classes
/resources/resource files
```

At program launch, I have a ResourceLoader class load up all of the resources I will need.  Because I have so many resource files I'm pulling from, I used the following method in code:

```
private static Scanner loadScanner(String fileName, ClassLoader classLoader) throws IOException, NullPointerException {
    File file;      
    Scanner sc;

    try { //to load the resource file
        file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());

    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        throw new NullPointerException("File " + fileName + " not found in ResourceLoader.loadScanner()");
    }
    sc = new Scanner(file);
    return sc;
}
```

I call the method with something like:

```
String fileName = "example.csv";
ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
sc = loadScanner(fileName,classLoader);
```

The error message I am getting is:

```
file:\C:\...\myjar.jar!\example.csv (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

My assumption is that the jar code is looking for a resources folder, and it's not there.  How do I need to modify my code or project/jar specs to get it working the way I expect?  Appreciate any help.

Also, for educational purposes, the jar file seems to suppress exceptions...?  If it can't find the resource file, then why doesn't my NullPointerException catch trigger?

Comment: `File` cannot be used to read a "file" inside a JAR. Instead, read it as a stream, e.g. something like `try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName))) { ... }`.

Comment: that fixed everything.  Thank you!